# Flutter Anchored Adaptive Test Ad hides textfield until it reloads

Tags: flutter

I am running into a very consistent issue that occurs all the time:

Flutter Anchored Adaptive Test Ad hides textfield until it reloads.

I have a basic screen with one textfield and a bunch of buttons with a single test ad.

Before the ad reloads, the textfield becomes hidden.

After the ad is loaded, the textfield is shown again.

I don't have a code to show/hide any UI fields.

I don't understand what's going on.

Any feedback/suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you

The following is a sample code, but it is not the same exact code that I have:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: MyForm())));
  }
}

class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyForm> createState() => MyFormState();
}

class MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  static TextEditingController mc = TextEditingController();
  static TextEditingController mc2 = TextEditingController();
  static TextEditingController mc3 = TextEditingController();

  static final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey2 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey3 = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  BannerAd? anchoredAdaptiveAd;
  bool isLoaded = false;
  late Orientation currentOrientation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    anchoredAdaptiveAd?.dispose();
    isLoaded = false;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
    loadAd();
  }

  /// Load another ad, disposing of the current ad if there is one.
  Future<void> loadAd() async {
    await anchoredAdaptiveAd?.dispose();
    setState(() {
      anchoredAdaptiveAd = null;
      isLoaded = false;
    });

    final AnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize? size = await AdSize
        .getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .size
        .width
        .truncate());

    if (size == null) {
      print('Unable to get height of anchored banner.');
      return;
    }

    anchoredAdaptiveAd = BannerAd(adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid
        ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111'
        : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716',
      size: size,
      request: AdRequest(),
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          print('$ad loaded: ${ad.responseInfo}');
          setState(() {
            // When the ad is loaded, get the ad size and use it to set
            // the height of the ad container.
            anchoredAdaptiveAd = ad as BannerAd;
            isLoaded = true;
          });
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          print('Anchored adaptive banner failedToLoad: $error');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );
    return anchoredAdaptiveAd!.load();
  }

  /// Gets a widget containing the ad, if one is loaded.
  ///
  /// Returns an empty container if no ad is loaded, or the orientation
  /// has changed. Also loads a new ad if the orientation changes.
  Widget getAdWidget() {
    return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      if (currentOrientation == orientation && anchoredAdaptiveAd != null && isLoaded) {
        //return Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,body: Container(width: anchoredAdaptiveAd!.size.width.toDouble(),height: anchoredAdaptiveAd!.size.height.toDouble(),child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: AdWidget(ad: anchoredAdaptiveAd!))])));
        return Container(constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),color:Colors.limeAccent,width: anchoredAdaptiveAd!.size.width.toDouble(),height: anchoredAdaptiveAd!.size.height.toDouble(),child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[Expanded(child: SizedBox(width: 800,height: 80, child:AdWidget(ad: anchoredAdaptiveAd!)))]));
      }
      // Reload the ad if the orientation changes.
      if (currentOrientation != orientation) {
        currentOrientation = orientation;
        loadAd();
      }
      return Container();
    },
    );
  }

  d1(){

  }

  d2(){

  }

  d3(){

  }

  d4(){

  }

  d5(){

  }

  d6(){

  }

  c1(){

  }

  c2(){

  }

  c3(){

  }

  c4(){

  }

  c5(){

  }

  c6(){

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget space = SizedBox(width: 100, height: 10, child: Text(""));
    Widget myinput = SizedBox(width: 800,height: 60,child: Form(key: formKey,child: TextFormField(autofocus: true,keyboardType: TextInputType.text,decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'test1',border: OutlineInputBorder()),controller: mc)));
    Widget myinput2 = SizedBox(width: 800,height: 60,child: Form(key: formKey2,child: TextFormField(autofocus: true,keyboardType: TextInputType.text,decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'test2',border: OutlineInputBorder()),controller: mc2)));
    Widget myinput3 = SizedBox(width: 800,height: 60,child: Form(key: formKey3,child: TextFormField(autofocus: true,keyboardType: TextInputType.text,decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'test3',border: OutlineInputBorder()),controller: mc3)));
    Widget myButtons = SizedBox(width: 800,height: 30,child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: d1,child: Text("t1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: d2,child: Text("t2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: d3,child: Text("t3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: d4,child: Text("t4", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: d5,child: Text("t5", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: d6,child: Text("t6", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
        ]));
    Widget myButtons2= SizedBox(width: 800,height: 30,child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: c1,child: Text("c1", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: c2,child: Text("c2", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: c3,child: Text("c3", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: c4,child: Text("c4", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: c5,child: Text("c5", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
          Expanded(child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: c6,child: Text("c6", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)))),
        ]));
    Widget myAd = SizedBox(width: 800,height: 80,child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: [Expanded(child: SizedBox(width: 800,height: 80, child:getAdWidget()))]));
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("TestBar",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),centerTitle: true,toolbarHeight: 35),body: Container(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      space,
                      myinput,
                      space,
                      myinput2,
                      space,
                      myinput3,
                      space,
                      myButtons,
                      space,
                      myButtons2,
                      space,
                      myAd,
                      space,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```